# radio button show unchecked when page load in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have included given code

```
<%= form_for @order, :url => update_checkout_path(:payment), :html => { :id => "checkout_form_payment" } do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :cod%>
    <%= form.radio_button :cod, @order.cod %>
<%end%>
```

and it shows cod radio button as checked and I want to show as unchecked and when I click on it than it will checked and value will be true. Please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= form_for @order, :url => update_checkout_path(:payment), :html => { :id => "checkout_form_payment" } do |form| %>
  <%= form.label :cod%>
  <%= form.radio_button :cod, @order.cod, checked: false %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/radio_button

That documentation states that the second argument to `radio_button` does **not** define whether the button will appear checked or not. Instead it defines what the **checked** value is. Since you are passing in the current value of the field, it is only natural that the radio button **always** appears as checked.

Note that the form helper methods know about the form object. You don't usually have to manually initialize a value. Try this in your form:

`form.radio_button :cod`  (do not pass in any other arguments)

HTH!